# Is this insect a bedbug?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I just found this bug on our bed. So even though it is literally a bedbug… is it actually a bedbug? We have never had an issue before and no signs of bites. But finding this worries me now…

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you searched for pictures of bedbugs? Does yours look like any of them? What makes you think it might be a bedbug?

Comment: Yes, I’ve searched for pictures of bedbugs. As someone who isnt a bug expert — honestly, its hard to tell just by looking at pictures. I believe someone who knows bugs well would have an easier time identifying the pictures I submitted, which is why I asked.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/101161/what-kind-of-bug-is-this-on-my-curtain/101163#101163) your question? This is a common question here.